# Jet Essentials not running with Excel - Possible ODBC SQL Native Client issue

Tags: odbc, jet

I'm using jet essentials on office 365 excel and the sql db is linked with a crm nav 2013. The problem is strictly with a single workstation because other workstations are able to connect to the server to generate reports.
I am getting the following error below when trying to run a report using Jet Essentials and I do have the latest and required drivers under my ODBC data source: SQL Server Native Client 11.0. When I searched online, it was mentioned that the problem is with the ODBC - SQL Native Client but I have the required version install. What could be causing the disconnect in db communication?

Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
   at ADODB.ConnectionClass.Open(String ConnectionString, String UserID, String Password, Int32 Options)
   at Jet.Data.Ado.AdoDataSource.a..ctor(String connectionString)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I found and installed the original SQL client used on the server to match the exact version and removed all previous registry files prior to the install. Finally, I used the web service on Excel to communicate between JET and the DB, and it worked!